# I don't understand SVG scaling. Svg is not it's full canvas width and height

Tags: html, css, svg

I want this svg to be 69px width and height. But it's not scaling or I don't understand viewbox.
[picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV0kk.png)

I understand that width and height applies to `rect`, `path` etc and `viewbox` is the canvas in which the svg is inside.

AS you can see from the code snippet below. The svg is 69px, but the logo inside sticks to the top left corner, but I want it to be as wide an tall as possible: 69px

```html
<svg width="69" height="69" viewBox="0 0 23 23" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.4415 6.28449C10.4415 7.10822 10.4463 7.93207 10.4381 8.75576C10.4361 8.95977 10.5112 9.03203 10.713 9.02471C11.0684 9.01173 11.4277 9.0434 11.7797 9.00514C12.7047 8.90464 13.4368 8.49129 13.8053 7.60841C14.1704 6.73343 14.1651 5.83436 13.8403 4.94898C13.5425 4.1373 12.8973 3.74903 12.0656 3.6199C11.6197 3.55068 11.1704 3.58806 10.7227 3.58223C10.4551 3.57876 10.4422 3.59445 10.4418 3.85541C10.4407 4.6651 10.4414 5.47479 10.4415 6.28449ZM5.98329 6.20077C5.98329 4.89727 5.98184 3.59381 5.98462 2.29031C5.98513 2.06529 6.00176 1.84022 6.01377 1.61529C6.05083 0.922079 6.61303 0.369839 7.27299 0.263374C7.46967 0.23162 7.66715 0.213693 7.86776 0.214073C9.54884 0.216906 11.2301 0.20215 12.911 0.219655C14.2466 0.233565 15.4895 0.594481 16.5741 1.3772C17.6351 2.14283 18.2553 3.20655 18.4851 4.47521C18.7648 6.01934 18.7748 7.55987 18.2195 9.0582C17.6923 10.4806 16.6843 11.4255 15.2541 11.9599C14.3371 12.3026 13.3866 12.3915 12.4238 12.4004C10.9636 12.4138 9.50323 12.408 8.04298 12.4028C7.47219 12.4007 6.95239 12.2657 6.52485 11.8465C6.11906 11.4488 5.97962 10.9621 5.97598 10.4283C5.96645 9.01918 5.97274 7.60993 5.97274 6.20077H5.98329Z" fill="black"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.62759 7.66138C4.57612 8.67961 4.61447 9.66663 4.57702 10.6511C4.53697 11.7049 3.84084 12.5047 2.67921 12.5854C2.10363 12.6254 1.54002 12.6071 1.01745 12.3268C0.417807 12.005 0.115548 11.4857 0.0332615 10.8337C-0.0233346 10.3855 0.0103495 9.93313 0.00808393 9.48266C0.00295437 8.47551 0.00739998 7.46837 2.34042e-05 6.46122C-0.00136301 6.26698 0.0585673 6.15704 0.254303 6.0836C1.23221 5.71668 2.20494 5.33615 3.17828 4.9573C3.56209 4.80792 3.94194 4.64865 4.32499 4.49732C4.60865 4.38519 4.62703 4.39787 4.62729 4.69385C4.62806 5.69398 4.62759 6.69406 4.62759 7.66138Z" fill="black"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.0324214 3.16745C0.0566586 2.70299 -0.0246875 2.12373 0.113853 1.55369C0.343614 0.608484 1.10364 0.0115526 2.08552 0.000855396C2.5353 -0.00404927 2.97858 0.00707082 3.40737 0.172054C4.10045 0.438639 4.6214 1.16368 4.63196 1.90255C4.63538 2.14191 4.61777 2.38254 4.63705 2.62041C4.6553 2.84581 4.56994 2.95562 4.35638 3.03722C3.11665 3.51082 1.88252 3.99879 0.646386 4.4816C0.50092 4.53843 0.352762 4.58887 0.209434 4.65044C0.0699954 4.71035 0.0308826 4.65496 0.0316092 4.52393C0.0338321 4.10851 0.0324214 3.6931 0.0324214 3.16745Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: why do you think it's not 69px high?

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use an external editor (like https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), as there would be too many changes to be made within `path` and `d`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 69 69" style="enable-background:new 0 0 69 69;width: 69px;height: 69px;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M38.6,34.4c0,3,0,6.1,0,9.1c0,0.8,0.3,1,1,1c1.3,0,2.6,0.1,3.9-0.1c3.4-0.4,6.1-1.9,7.5-5.2
    c1.3-3.2,1.3-6.6,0.1-9.8c-1.1-3-3.5-4.4-6.6-4.9c-1.6-0.3-3.3-0.1-5-0.1c-1,0-1,0-1,1C38.6,28.5,38.6,31.4,38.6,34.4z M22.1,34.1
    c0-4.8,0-9.6,0-14.4c0-0.8,0.1-1.7,0.1-2.5c0.1-2.6,2.2-4.6,4.7-5c0.7-0.1,1.5-0.2,2.2-0.2c6.2,0,12.4,0,18.6,0
    c4.9,0.1,9.5,1.4,13.5,4.3c3.9,2.8,6.2,6.8,7.1,11.4c1,5.7,1.1,11.4-1,16.9c-1.9,5.3-5.7,8.7-11,10.7C53,56.7,49.5,57,45.9,57
    c-5.4,0-10.8,0-16.2,0c-2.1,0-4-0.5-5.6-2.1c-1.5-1.5-2-3.3-2-5.2C22,44.5,22.1,39.3,22.1,34.1L22.1,34.1z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M17.1,39.5c-0.2,3.8,0,7.4-0.2,11c-0.1,3.9-2.7,6.8-7,7.1c-2.1,0.1-4.2,0.1-6.1-1c-2.2-1.2-3.3-3.1-3.6-5.5
    c-0.2-1.7-0.1-3.3-0.1-5c0-3.7,0-7.4,0-11.2c0-0.7,0.2-1.1,0.9-1.4c3.6-1.4,7.2-2.8,10.8-4.2c1.4-0.6,2.8-1.1,4.2-1.7
    c1-0.4,1.1-0.4,1.1,0.7C17.1,32.3,17.1,36,17.1,39.5z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M0.1,22.9c0.1-1.7-0.2-3.9,0.3-6c0.8-3.5,3.7-5.7,7.3-5.7c1.7,0,3.3,0,4.9,0.6c2.6,1,4.5,3.7,4.5,6.4
    c0,0.9-0.1,1.8,0,2.7c0.1,0.8-0.2,1.2-1,1.5C11.5,24.2,7,26,2.4,27.8c-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.4-1.6,0.6c-0.5,0.2-0.7,0-0.7-0.5
    C0.1,26.4,0.1,24.9,0.1,22.9z"/>
</svg>
```

Basically the changes to `width` and `height` (to 68px) only apply to the canvas but the content is inside path so you should, point by point, move the image.

It is doable but it is hard work, I prefer to help myself with external editors.

Comment: Those editors add a lot of (deprecated) junk. Use https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ And even that file has xml and class attributes you can remove

Comment: Thanks, I used some online free svg scaler and that did the trick! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i was having issues with svg scaling also recently. What i found helpful was this post by css-tricks. I will attach the link here: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

i hope this brings more clarity to your issue :)

edit: playing around with the svg you provided i changed the aspect ratio and viewbox to fit in the svg (making it 'scale' to the wanted width, with reduced height in order to preserve its aspect ratio without distorting or cutting the svg).
here is what i changed:

```
<svg width="69" height="49" viewBox="0 -2 17 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```